# Escaping white space : %20 or + - smarty

Tags: php, escaping, smarty

I am using smarty as a template engine. I have to escape an image file path {$filepath|urlencode}, the problem is that the white space are converted into a '+', which prevent the image to be reached on the server : %20 would work, how to escape correctly my path ?
Edit : more precisely, I use the facebook share  link

I use a facebook share as so and it doesn't display the image when shared :

```
`<a href="facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={$fbappid}&amp;link={$mainsite|‌​escape:'u‌​rl'}{$someurl|urlencode}&amp;picture={$mainsite|escape:'url'}{$picture()‌​|escape‌​:"url"}&amp;name={$somename}&amp;description=Join%20Us%21 &amp;redirect_uri={$mainsite|escape:'url'}{$some|urlencode}" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;"></a>`
```

The final code looks like for my specific usage :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=...&amp;link=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Dcampaign%26campaign_id%3D18&amp;picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org%2Ffiles%2Fcampaign%2Fimage%2Foriginals%2F18%2FSans+titre-3.jpg&amp;name=Some text &quot;Text d&#039;Text&quot;, Text&amp;description=Rejoignez%20la%20campagne%21&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Dcampaign%26campaign_id%3D18"onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">
```

on the same site, all the facebook share link works perfectly and the image displays well ! Reason why I thought it was the link of that specific image that is not working

Answer (score 4):

escape is what you're searching for. Take a look at:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

```
 {$filepath|escape:"url"}
```

urlencode is used to encode (not escape!) a string to be used as a query part inside an URL passed as GET var: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Okay - what image precisely does not show up? preview thumbnail on facebook (not on your website!) using the share button?

How do you define the preview image in your markup? og:image or via <link rel="image_src" /> ?

Comment: The image displays fine on my website but not in the facebook's preview thumbnail. the image is indeed defined like an og object? But I think the link that is used by facebook is the one specified in http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?... What is weired is that the open graph link taht I found in facebook's debugger : http://graph.facebook.com/195459563930903 refers to this http://primagora.org/files/campaign/image/originals/18/Sans\u002520titre-3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

URL encoded space is either a plus sign or `%20`. They are equivalent, and are both interpreted as a space on the server.

If you see either in the URL, then the server will see a space.

You say that the plus sign is preventing the image from being loaded. This sounds like a deeper problem than simply using the wrong encoding. Possibly it's being double-encoded?

What is the actual URL being requested in the browser? Open the dev tools/Firebug, and look at the requests to find out. If the URL includes `%2B` then the plus sign is being double-encoded. This is the problem you need to solve.

The other solution, of course, is not to use spaces in filenames on the web. The only reason one would want spaces in filenames is for readability, but since the web requires spaces to be urlencoded, it removes that readability anyway. Take away the spaces, and the problem will go away by itself.

Comment: The code you've shown in the comment is the smarty code; what does the finished HTML code look like in the browser? In particular the URL? (BTW -- when posting additional info like that, it's better to edit it into the question than as a comment; it's easier to read and keeps all the relevant info together in one place)